# Get instanceID in Http triggered orchestration Starter function in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

[InstanceId: (Optional) The unique ID of the instance. If not specified, a random instance ID will be generated.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-instance-management)

is there a way to get the random generated instance ID in Http triggered orchestration Starter function in nodeJs language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's about js `DurableOrchestrationClient` APIs like c# [StartNewAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-instance-management#starting-instances) to get InstanceId when orchestrator function starts, it has not been [implemented](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js#api-implementation-checklist) yet.

So in the [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/blob/master/test/sample/HttpStartJS/index.js), it creates a uuid (Universal Unique Identifier) to initialize the id explicitly. In this way, we have the random generated instance ID as well.

```
const uuidv1 = require("uuid/v1");

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    const id = uuidv1();

    let startArgs = [{
        FunctionName: req.params.functionName,
        Input: req.body,
        InstanceId: id
    }];

    context.bindings.starter = startArgs;

    context.done(null, {status: 202, body: id});
};
```